# Only query a Firestore Document if it has been updated?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Suppose I have a simple Document:

```
Company
(sub collections)
- employees
(fields)
- name
- address
```

Since the list of employees in a Company probably won't change often, it would cut down on my number of reads if I could cache the information and only update it when it has changed. I know that Firestore has offline persistence, but it isn't clear in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) exactly what's going on behind the scenes. Is there a way for Firestore to handle this automatically, or would I need to add a `last_updated` field to each employee document and query for employees updated more recently than the last time my client executed the query?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see if a document in Firestore has been updated from a client app, the only way to do that is to actually read it.  There's no substitute for that.  The offline persistence only kicks in and serves queries when the Firestore cloud service is unavailable, or if you use a [source option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options) to indicate that you only want to look at the cache.

You could indeed have a client query for only updates to documents where a last_updated field is greater than the time of its last query.  Be aware that it still costs at least 1 read to execute that query, even if the query yields no documents, which covers the cost of accessing the underlying index.

You might also choose to use Cloud Functions to trigger on a document change, then use a push notification to tell the client that a document is updated.  It can then go read that document to store in the cache.

Bear in mind that if you lean too heavily on the client cache, you could run into trouble when documents get purged for whatever reason (for example, if its capacity is exceeded). Nothing will tell you when that happens, and now your local cache is serving incomplete results.  You should have your own local cache/database that you fully control, in order to avoid that situation.

Comment: I thought you only got billed for a read when you actually return a document from a query, not each document the query goes over, hence pagination.

Comment: You get billed at least one document read for any query, even if it returns no documents.  Otherwise you pay per document. Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#minimum-charge